# Execute Functions in a FIFO queue with Thread Locking

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to execute function calls in a FIFO queue and get the results from each call.

```
def func1(arg1):
    return arg1
def func2(arg1):
    return arg1
```

I will call these functions from different threads at random times. So basically what I want is that only one of these functions is executed at a time and I want to be able to get the return values from each call.

Comment: So where's your queue? And where are your threads? You can hardly expect us to write all of that for you.

Comment: I think the question is concerned with multi-function dispatch and thread locking, not the implementation of a queue and threads. It could be clearer, but possibly there's a second language issue here?

Comment: @majidse could you make your question clearer? I'm still not sure whether you want a single-function block or a multi-function block (as in the duck-swift-sloth example in the second answer.) I'm happy to help you edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import threading
import time


def func1(arg1):
    return arg1

def func2(arg1):
    return arg1

def square(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x * x

one_at_a_time = threading.Lock()
action_to_func_mapping = {
    "action1": func1,
    "action2": func2,
    "square_number": square,
}

def dispatch(action, arg1):
    one_at_a_time.acquire()
    func_to_call = action_to_func_mapping[action]
    func_result = func_to_call(arg1)
    one_at_a_time.release()
    return func_result
```

Here's an example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    square_result = dispatch('square_number', 2)
    print(square_result)
    func1_result = dispatch('action1', 3)
    print(func1_result)


>>> python dispatch.py
4
3
```

You can't see the effect of the lock here: the example is single-threaded and there will never be any contention between threads. You could update the question with some simple threaded code to show the lock in action.

In a multi-threaded context the above code will block other threads and wait for the first thread to finish executing its function. In your application you may be able to do something more efficient. For example you might have one lock per function, rather than a single one-at-a-time funnel for all function calls:

```
action_to_func_mapping = {
    "action1": func1,
    "action2": func2,
    "square_number": square,
}
action_to_func_with_perfunc_lock = {action: (func, threading.Lock())
     for action, func in action_to_func_mapping.items()}


def dispatch(action, arg1):
    func_to_call, func_lock = action_to_func_with_perfunc_lock[action]
    func_lock.acquire()
    func_result = func_to_call(arg1)
    func_lock.release()
    return func_result

>>> python dispatch.py
4
3
```

This time a `square_number` will block the next `square_number` until the first has finished but an `action1` or `action2` are not blocked by a `square_number` call.

Some Python facilities used here: [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), tuple unpacking.

Comment: You got my question right. I'm trying to use your code in my application to see how it works. Also you are right about second language problem:). Thanks.

Comment: glad we're on the same page @majidse. I've added a per-function locking example-- it wasn't clear whether you wanted per-function locking or a one-at-a-time funnel for all function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example with a FIFO queue and threads, contrasting per-function locks and a one-at-a-time lock. The previous answer is correct but can't demonstrate locking strategies and their effects because the code there is single-threaded. The present answer introduces threads so that thread - locking does occur and you can see the result.

```
import threading
from collections import deque
from time import sleep, time


def duck(behaviour):
    sleep(1)
    return behaviour


def sloth(behaviour):
    sleep(5)
    return behaviour


def swift(behaviour):
    sleep(0.1)
    return behaviour


animal_to_func = {
    "sloth": sloth,
    "duck": duck,
    "swift": swift,
}
one_at_a_time_lock = threading.Lock()
animal_to_func_with_per_animal_lock = {action: (func, threading.Lock())
                                       for action, func in animal_to_func.items()}

fifo = deque()


class AnimalThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, use_per_animal_lock=False):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.use_per_animal_lock = use_per_animal_lock

    def run(self):
        while len(fifo):
            animal, behaviour = fifo.popleft()
            animal_action = dispatch(animal, behaviour, self.use_per_animal_lock)
            print('  (thread %s) %s: %s' % (self.thread_id, animal, str(animal_action)))


def dispatch(animal, behaviour, use_per_animal_lock=False):
    if use_per_animal_lock:
        animal_function, lock = animal_to_func_with_per_animal_lock[animal]
    else:
        lock = one_at_a_time_lock
        animal_function = animal_to_func[animal]
    lock.acquire()
    what_just_happened = animal_function(behaviour)
    lock.release()
    return what_just_happened


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monday_morning = [
        ('sloth', 'wake up'),
        ('sloth', 'blink'),
        ('sloth', 'go back to sleep'),
        ('duck', 'wake up'),
        ('duck', 'quack'),
        ('duck', 'waddle'),
        ('duck', 'swim'),
        ('duck', 'fight duck #2'),
        ('duck', 'quack'),
        ('swift', 'wake up'),
        ('swift', 'catch insects'),
        ('swift', 'feed chicks'),
    ]
    # essentially unlimited threads to force locks to be used
    no_of_threads = len(monday_morning)
    print('One at a time, no pushing and shoving!...')
    # load the FIFO queue the threads will consume
    fifo.extend(monday_morning)
    # start threads
    threads = [AnimalThread(i) for i in range(no_of_threads)]
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    # wait for threads to finish
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]
    print('One of each kind of animal at a time...')
    # load the FIFO queue the threads will consume
    fifo.extend(monday_morning)
    # start threads
    threads = [AnimalThread(threadno, use_per_animal_lock=True) for threadno in range(no_of_threads)]
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    # wait for threads to finish
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]
```

And here's an example run:

```
 One at a time, no pushing and shoving!...
   (thread 0) sloth: wake up
   (thread 1) sloth: blink
   (thread 2) sloth: go back to sleep
   (thread 3) duck: wake up
   (thread 4) duck: quack
   (thread 5) duck: waddle
   (thread 6) duck: swim
   (thread 7) duck: fight duck #2
   (thread 8) duck: quack
   (thread 9) swift: wake up
   (thread 10) swift: catch insects
   (thread 11) swift: feed chicks
 One of each kind of animal at a time...
   (thread 9) swift: wake up
   (thread 10) swift: catch insects
   (thread 11) swift: feed chicks
   (thread 3) duck: wake up
   (thread 4) duck: quack
   (thread 5) duck: waddle
   (thread 6) duck: swim
   (thread 0) sloth: wake up
   (thread 7) duck: fight duck #2
   (thread 8) duck: quack
   (thread 1) sloth: blink
   (thread 2) sloth: go back to sleep
```

The one-at-a-time lock follows the order of the items in the FIFO queue. It's a funnel that only allows one function call at once. The trouble with it is that it effectively converts a multiple-thread application into a serial, single-thread one.

When there's a per-animal lock in the above code, the animals Can only do one thing at a time  (the sloth can't wake up and blink at the same time) but they are independent of each other and can get on with their own lives. The swift finishes before the duck and the sloth even wake up. But because the duck is having a busy morning and can only do one thing at a time, the sloth wakes up before the duck has finished.

This kind of locking is useful in time-sensitive applications where functions of a certain type need to be processed in the order they arrive on the queue. Money transactions are one example, where you might have several units of work related to one account, and these have to be processed in the order they arrive on the queue.